How many positive integer $n$ less than $2024$ satisfy both $n \equiv1,2,3,5,6,7 \mod 8$ and $n \equiv1,2,3,10,11,12 \mod 15$
I am currently working to a problem. After several manipulation I got this modular system
$$n \equiv1,2,3,5,6,7 \mod 8$$
$$n \equiv1,2,3,10,11,12 \mod 15$$
n is positive integer less than 2024
I think it can be solved by Chinese Remainder Theorem. But, since there are 6 variation for first equation and six for the second equation then there will be 36 variation of Chinese Remainder Theorem. So I guess it is not executable.
My next idea is to find how many solution for $n=1,2,3,...120$ because 120 is lcm of 8 and 15. Once obtained I can deduce all number of the solution by using iteration. I working on it manually so I get $$n=1,2,3,10,11,17,18,...$$ the list are still going on. I would prefer to have another simpler idea. Any help would be very appreciated

When you write $n\equiv 1,2,3,...,7\bmod 8$, do you mean $x\equiv 1\bmod 8$ or $x\equiv 2\bmod 8$... ?

I'd say it was easier to look for those that don't satisfy any pair of those congruences.  You need $n\equiv 0 \pmod 4$ for instance in order to violate the first one.  This greatly reduces the number of congruences you need to evaluate.

Yes, that is exactly what I mean. But n is not congruent to 4 mod 8 @JoshuaTilley

Thanks for the idea, but to look for those that don't satisfy, we  use $n((A\cap B)')=n(A' \cup B')$ so the second equation need also to be $n\equiv 0,4,5,6,7,8,9,13,14 \mod 15$. @lulu

Addendum added to prove the assertion that the probability oriented approach, with independent events, as I have used it, is valid.

When you are examining subsets of numbers, such that each subset represents $~60~$ consecutive numbers, then the problem can be re-interpreted to be a probability problem.
For example, in the subset $~\{1,2,\cdots,60\},~$ exactly $~\dfrac{6}{15} \times 60~$ of the numbers will satisfy the second constraint.
Further, since $~15~$ is relatively prime to $~4,~$ and since the first constraint can be re-expressed as eliminating multiples of $~4,~$ then in the set of $~60~$ consecutive numbers, the first constraint can be regarded as independent of the 2nd constraint.
Therefore, the number of satisfying numbers in the set $~\{1,2,3,\cdots,60\}~$ is
$$60 \times \frac{6}{15} \times \frac{3}{4} = 18.$$
Then, you have that $~33 \times 60 = 1980.~$
Therefore, in the set $~\{1,2,\cdots,1980\},~$ there are $~18 \times 33 = 594~$ satisfying numbers.
So, the problem reduces to determining how many satisfying numbers that there are in the set $~\{1981, 1982, \cdots, 2023\},~$ which will be the same as the number of satisfying numbers in the set $~\{1,2,\cdots,43\}.$
Perhaps simplest is to list them:
  1    2    3   10   11   12
 16   17   18   25   26   27
 31   32   33   40   41   42

Of the above $~18~$ numbers that satisfy the 2nd constraint, $~4~$ of them must be eliminated as multiples of $~4.$
Therefore, the final enumeration is
$$594 + 14 = 608.$$



$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$
Comments have been left, following this answer, that indicate that I should prove the assertion of independent events.
That is, I asserted that because $~15~$ is relatively prime to $~4,~$ and because you were examining a set of $~(4 \times 15)~$ consecutive integers, that you could regard congruence $~\pmod{4}~$ to be independent of congruence $~\pmod{15}.$
This seems like a reasonable criticism of my answer.  So, I will prove the assertion now.

Let $~m,n~$ be elements in $~\Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}},~$ such that $~m,n~$ are relatively prime.
Let $~S~$ denote the set
$\{ ~0, ~1, ~2, ~\cdots, ~[ ~(m \times n) - 1 ~] ~\}.~$ 
So, $~S~$ has exactly $~( ~m\times n ~)~$ elements.
Let $~a~$ be any element in
$~\{0,1,2,\cdots, m-1\}.$
Let $~T~$ denote the subset of $~S~$ specified as 
$\{a + km ~: ~k \in \Bbb{Z}, ~0 \leq k \leq (n-1) ~\}.$
So, $~T~$ represents the $~n~$ elements in $~S~$ that are all congruent to $~a \pmod{m}.~$

Lemma 1
If $~t_1,t_2 \in T,~$ such that $~t_1 < t_2,~$ then $~n~$ does not divide
$~(t_2 - t_1).$
Proof
Since $~t_1, ~t_2 \in S,~$ with $~t_1 < t_2,~$ then $~(t_2 - t_1) \in S,~$ with $~(t_2 - t_1) > 0.$
Suppose that $~n~$ divides $~(t_2 - t_1).~$  Then, $~(t_2 - t_1)~$ is a common multiple of $~m~$ and $~n.~$  Therefore, the least common multiple of $~(m,n)~$ divides $~(t_2 - t_1).$
Since $~(m,n)~$ are assumed relatively prime, $~(mn)~$ is the least common multiple of $~(m,n).$
Therefore, $~(t_2 - t_1)~$ is a multiple of $~mn.$
This yields a contradiction, because the only multiple of $~mn~$ in the set $~S~$ is $~0,~$ and it has been established that $~(t_2 - t_1)~$ is an element in $~S~$ that is greater than $~0.$

Lemma 2
For each element $~b~$ in $~\{0,1,2,\cdots,n-1\},~$ there exists exactly $~1~$ element $~t \in T~$ such that $~t \equiv b \pmod{n}.~$
Proof
By Lemma 1, none of the $~n~$ elements in $~T~$ are congruent to each other $~\pmod{n}.~$
Therefore, each of the congruence classes $~\pmod{n}~$ in $~\{0,1,2,\cdots,n-1\},~$ must be represented by exactly $~1~$ element in $~T.~$

Suppose that you are given that $~m,n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}},~$ such that $~m,n~$ are relatively prime.
Further suppose that you are examining the elements in the set $~S = 
\{ ~0, ~1, ~2, ~\cdots, ~[ ~(m \times n) - 1 ~] ~\}.~$
For $~a \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,m-1\},~$ and 
$~b \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,n-1\}~$ :

Let $~E_m(a)~$ denote the event that a random element $~s \in S~$ is congruent to $~a \pmod{m}.$

Let $~E_n(b)~$ denote the event that a random element $~s \in S~$ is congruent to $~b \pmod{n}.$


Lemma 2 provides the foundation for asserting that $~E_m(a)~$ and $~E_n(b)~$ are independent events.
That is, clearly, the probability of $~E_n(b)~$ occurring is $~\dfrac{1}{n}.~$
Lemma 2 proves that if you are given that event $~E_m(a)~$ has occurred, then the probability of $~E_n(b)~$ occurring is still $~\dfrac{1}{n}.$
That is, $~p[ ~E_n(b) ~| ~E_m(a) ~] = p[ ~E_n(b) ~].$

So far, this independence of events has been demonstrated for the set $~S.~$
This independence of events $~E_m(a)~$
and $~E_n(b)~$ can be demonstrated for any set of $~(m \times n)~$ consecutive integers as follows:
Let $~S_1~$ denote any set of $~(m \times n)~$ consecutive integers. 
Construct the map from $~S_1~$ to $~S~$ such that $~s_1 \in S_1~$ maps to $~s \in S~$ if and only if $~s_1 \equiv s \pmod{mn}.$
Further, given any $~s_1 \in S_1,~$ let $~\overline{s_1}~$ denote the element in $~S~$ that $~s_1~$ maps to.
Lemma 3
The constructed map is a bijection from $~S_1~$ to $~S.$
Proof
Since $~S~$ represents the complete set of all congruence classes $~\pmod{mn},~$ each element in $~S_1~$ must map to exactly one of the elements in $~S.~$ 
Further, if $~s_1,s_2~$ are any two distinct elements in $~S_1,~$ such that $~s_1 < s_2,~$ then $~0 < (s_2 - s_1) < (mn).~$  This implies that $~mn~$ can not divide $~(s_2 - s_1).~$  This then implies that $~s_1~$ and $~s_2~$ can not both map to the same element in $~S.$

Lemma 4
For any $~a \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,m-1\},~$  let $~T_1~$ denote the subset of $~S_1~$ of all elements congruent to $~a \pmod{m}.$
Then, for each element $~b~$ in $~\{0,1,2,\cdots,n-1\},~$ there exists exactly $~1~$ element $~t_1 \in T_1~$ such that $~t_1 \equiv b \pmod{n}.~$
Proof
Define the analogous set $~T \subset S~$ to represent all elements in $~S~$ that are congruent to $~a \pmod{m}.$
By Lemma 2, there exists exactly one element $~t \in T~$ such that $~t \equiv b \pmod{n}.$
Further, each of the $~n~$ elements in $~T_1~$ maps to a distinct element in $~T.$ Therefore, there exists exactly one element $~t_1~$ in $~T_1~$ such that $~\overline{t_1} = t.~$
Therefore, $~t_1~$ is the unique element in $~T_1~$ such that $~t_1 \equiv b \pmod{n}.$

In the set $~S,~$ Lemma 2 provided the foundation for proving that $~E_m(a)~$ and $~E_n(b)~$ are independent events.
Similarly, Lemma 4, which is the set $~S_1~$ analogue lemma to Lemma 2, provides the foundation for extending the independence of $~E_m(a)~$ and $~E_n(b)~$ to $~S_1.$

Simpler: go one further to $\color{#0af}{34}$ chunks of $,4\times 15,,$ from which we need to subtract out the  $\color{#0a0}{\rm four}$ solutions in your (unshown)  final row $\require{cancel}\color{#0a0}{ ,46\ 47\ \color{#c00}{\cancel{48}}\ 55\ \color{#c00}{\cancel{56}}\ 57},,$ yielding a total of $:\color{#0af}{34}\cdot 18\color{#0a0}{-4} = 608.\ \ $

Generally the number of $\rm\color{#c00}{multiples}$ of $,\color{#c00}4,$ in the $k$'th row $,r+15k,\ r\in {1\ 2\ \color{darkorange}3\ 10\ \color{darkorange}{11}\ 12},$ is the number of $,r\equiv k\pmod{!4},,$ by $!\bmod 4!:\ 0\equiv r+15k\equiv r-k!\iff! r\equiv k,,$ e.g. for the final $,k=3,$ row in the prior comment: $,r\equiv 3\pmod{!4} !\iff! r = \color{darkorange}{3,11},,$ yielding $15(3)+{3\ 11} = \color{#c00}{\require{cancel}\cancel{48}, \cancel{56}}.\ \ $

@BillDubuque I considered going down that road, and then decided that it was a little too much for the target audience, the original poster.  That is, I thought that the concept of independent events would be enough of a burden.  So, to conclude the problem, I opted for the simplest (i.e. somewhat primitive) approach.

It can be said more simply: $!\bmod 4,,$ stepping up a column adds $:!{-}15\equiv 1,$ (i.e. an increment), so exactly one of the $4$ entries in each column is a multiple of $4$, which leaves $3$ solutions per column, so the $6$ columns yield $,6\cdot 3 = 18,$ solutions in each length $60$ period chunk. Beginners can easily justify that, but most will not be able to fill in the gap in your unjustified probabilistic claim. $\ \ $

I would actually avoid taking about probability, because the approach isn't correct and is based on the underlying idea of CRT which you didn't mention. For example, if we tried to solve $ x \equiv 1 \pmod{6}, x \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$, the number of solutions is actually 0, not $ \frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{4}$ (or any other multiplication) probabilistically. $\quad$  It is more important to explain why every pairing of the modulus would lead to a solution, and that's the CRT aspect. You stated that it's "independent", without quite providing a reason for it.

Thankyou very much for all of your answers, responses and sharing ideas. I very appreciate that. Honestly most of them are little bit hard for me to swallow. At last, I am okay with primitively find all the solutions, by inspection, for the first 60 values and then by iteration deduce all the solutions. @user2661923

@CalvinLin I disagree that my probability approach is wrong.  Your counter example violates the constraint that the two modulos (e.g. $~4~$ and $~15$) must be relatively prime.  Also, see the Addendum that I have just added to the end of my answer, which proves that my probability oriented approach is valid.

@BillDubuque See the Addendum that I have just added to the end of my answer, which proves that my probability oriented approach is valid.

@SaifulAhmadi See the Addendum that I have just added to the end of my answer, which proves that my probability oriented approach is valid.

@Saiful Your CRT approach works fine. To simplify work mod $60$  (vs. $120$), then proceed as in my first comment above. I can post more details in an answer if you like. $\ \ $

Thank you very much for the answer and all the effort you put on it. All of your posts above is more than enough and I really appreciate. And for your addendum, I think it’s super cool and I promise to put my effort to understand it too. I really have mad respect for you Sir. Thankyou. @BillDubuque
